# Two excel tables that have one identical column, can one auto update from the other?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table for inputting data and running calculations. This table has a lot of columns, so I create a second table for a printable output. The first column  in both tables is a unique value that is common to both tables, so the output table is basically a table that uses lookup functions to pull the required data or results out of the input table for each row.

What is the best way to make the first column in both tables always be identical as the end user adds and deletes rows from the input table? I've been trying to work out a macro so that every time a value is added to the first column of the input the value is copied to the last row of the first column of the output table, but then I don't know how it would work if a row was deleted, or if a duplicate value was added. Or I could use a macro that would copy and paste the entire column every time the input column was changed. Are there any obvious solutions I am missing that I should also be considering? I am pretty new to VBA, but once I figure out which direction would make things easiest for the end user I think I will be able to figure it out.

Update: For anyone else with a similar problem this is the code I ended up writing, it works great so far.
In the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

    Call Module1.UpdateOutput

End If


End Sub
```

In Module 1:

```
Sub UpdateOutput()

' UpdateOutput Macro

'Set active cell for return at end of macro
Dim ActCell As Range
Set ActCell = Selection

' Check Input table has data
If Sheet6.ListObjects("Input").DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
End If

'Count Selected Rows of Input and Output Table
Dim RowsIn As Long
RowsIn = Sheet6.ListObjects("Input").ListColumns("UWI").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
Dim RowsOut As Long
RowsOut = Sheet3.ListObjects("Results").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
Dim RowsCalc As Long
RowsCalc = Sheet1.ListObjects("IWCP").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Delete extra rows from Output Table
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = RowsOut + 1
Do While lRow >= RowsIn + 2
Sheet3.Rows(lRow).Delete
Sheet1.Rows(lRow + 1).Delete
lRow = lRow - 1
Loop

'Select UWI column from input table
Application.Goto Sheet6.ListObjects("Input").ListColumns("UWI").DataBodyRange
Selection.Copy

'Paste UWI column from input table
Sheet3.ListObjects("Results").ListColumns("UWI").DataBodyRange(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheet1.ListObjects("IWCP").ListColumns("UWI").DataBodyRange(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Return to previous cell
Application.Goto ActCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: TL;DR The best Stack Overflow questions have a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You should check out the [Help Page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as well.  So, shorten up your question, ask about a specific item you need help with, and post the code you have so far and show in that code where you are stuck.

Comment: @Xipha You should include a screenshot of your expected input / output in your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming both of your tables are in Sheet1. You have to insert in the module corresponding to Sheet1 the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngsrc As Range, rngtrg As Range
    Dim losrc As ListObject, lotrg As ListObject
    Set losrc = Me.ListObjects(1)
    Set lotrg = Me.ListObjects(2)
    'Set rngsrc = your_source_range_to_monitor
    Set rngsrc = losrc.ListColumns(1).Range
    Set rngtrg = lotrg.ListColumns(1).Range

    Dim ints As Range
    Set ints = Application.Intersect(rngsrc, Target)
    If (Not (ints Is Nothing)) Then
        ' Do your job to copy from rngsrc to rngtrg
        Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
        rngsrc.Copy
        rngtrg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    End If
End Sub
```

and modify as needed.